# Application crash with error - EGLFS: OpenGL windows cannot be mixed with others

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've created a very basic project in Qt Creator.

```
File -> New Project -> Application -> Qt QuickControls Application
```

Without adding / modifying anything, compiled the project and deployed on the target system which is a Olimex board with Qt (compiled with eglfs), using tslib. The application is started with

```
testApp -plugin tslib
```

Application starts and clicking on the File menu is killing it. "EGLFS: OpenGL windows cannot be mixed with others" error appears in the terminal.

This is the `main.qml` file.

import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered");
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Label {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the fact that there can only be one top OpenGL window and I'm not adding anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It probably creates a window to show the menu. I remember that similar thing happens while opening a ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the open issue, and it is work in progress.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38405